# IDE (Dev c++, visual express, code block, etc) doesn't work on my computer

Tags: c++, ide, codeblocks, dev-c++

I recently needed to code (C++) on my personal computer, so I installed an IDE.

At first I installed Eclipse CDT, which didn't include a compiler, so I added MinGW by myself. But I didn't manage to "link" it to Eclipse, so I decided to change my IDE.

However, everything failed. 
* CodeBlock (installed through the .exe which includes minGW) says he cannot find Visual C++ 2010 compiler
* Visual studio express 2010 just crash when I try to use the default code
* Dev C++ launch a console with nothing in it (instead of the intended "Hello World!"), which doesn't stop by pressing keys, and if closed "by hand", I cannot rerun the code because the previous one is still executing, while not shown on the process list. So I installed Process Explorer to find it, by I cannot kill it because I don't have permission. Of course, I am administrator on my computer.

So I think there is something wrong inside my computer, like an old installation, a bad configuration,... but all the IDE fail, in different ways.

I appreciate the time you spent reading my problem, and thank you very much for your help

Psycho

Comment: Did you try disabling your anti-virus software, if you are using any?

Comment: I didn't, I didn't think it can solve my problem. I'll try right now.

Comment: Oh my god it works !
Can you explain how it is linked ? Can I do something, like settings, not to disable my antivirus everytime I want to code ?

Comment: depending on how your anti-virus works, you should be able to set up exceptions for a whole directory

Comment: I'll have a look at it. On this computer I just have the free version of Avast